# Android: different modules for Tablet & Phone, but one single app published & listed

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

As stated in my question, I am going to develop an app to be published on Google Play, and that app will properly support phones and tablets.

This means the phone and tablet *apps* will share pretty much the same features, but will display possibily very different layouts in order to offer the best UX for these respective platforms.

At this point, I wanted to go about as following and was wondering if that was the correct way:

I believe **App Bundles** will help me achieve that, so let's assume I create a new Android Studio project from scratch.

Then, using `File > New > New Module`, which opens the module creation dialog, I would generate **two** `Phone * Tablet Module` and one `Android Library` module, a module that will contain all the shared same business logic, common to both aforementionned modules.

Then, using the Manifest, I would add the restriction to target phones and tablets separately.

I believe both app modules will need to have the same package name (application id).

Would that be the correct way ? Am I missing anything ? Is there a better standardized way to do so ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You only really want the layout to change, right? So just create different layouts for the different devices, you can add the qualifiers on creating a new layout file.
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes
Check this for further information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! 
Well, there is one case where the layout will be way too different in terms of architecture. For example, think of a list with items that can, upon click, expand to display further content.
On a phone, you'd have the full list linear from top to bottom. 
On a tablet, you'd have a side panel with the items listed like on the phone, but upon click, show item content in main panel/container. Do you get my meaning ? That means different adapters, holders etc. So it's not as simple as manipulating XML layout.

Comment: Well you can also check in code with what you're dealing with (which xml is displayed) and act accordingly.

Comment: I would to this with fragments, I have read something very similar to what you want to achieve in the Big Nerd Ranche guide, so if you're a beginner anyway, doesn't hurt to pick it up ;)

Comment: Yes thank you. In the end I followed a solution here on SO, where I create a bool resource "isTablet" set to true only in values/sw-600dp. Then, wherever needed, I can access said bool and apply the proper logic. So, then, using your idea, I'd have different Fragments where needed for tablet & phones. And with Databinding, it works like a charm. Excellent ! Do you think I should submit this idea in an answer and validate it ?